# perl replace space with tab

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to replace each two spaces from the beginning of each line, with a tab.
I tried the following:

```
s/^(\s{2})+/\t/gm;
```

it didnt work.

Comment: that will replace in the WHOLE string, I need only at the beginning of each line.

Comment: use `--first-only` (gnu unexpand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're reading the file line by line:

```
$line =~ s/\G[ ]{2}/\t/g;
```

If you've slurped the entire file:

```
$file =~ s/(?:\G|^)[ ]{2}/\t/mg;
```

Comment: forgot about the existence of \G, now I will no longer forget it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about [this](http://codepad.org/2HM1ua1r)?

```
my $test_string = "  some test stuff\ndivided to\n  provide the challenge";
$test_string =~ s/^[ ]{2}/\t/gm;
print $test_string;
```

Explanation: `\s` is actually not a single symbol alias, but a character 'whitespace' class: it includes both `\n\` and `\t` for example. If you want to replace only spaces, use spaces in your regexes; setting a character class (instead of just `/^ {2}/...` to me is more readable (and won't break with the `/x` [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)).

Besides, if you want to replace just *two* space symbols, you don't need to use `+` quantifier.

UPDATE: if you need to replace *each* two spaces, I guess I'd use this instead:

```
$test_string =~ s#^((?:[ ]{2})+)#"\t" x (length($1)/2)#gme;
```

... or just \G anchor as in the ikegami's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the `+` quantifier means “one or more of,” and it’s applied to `\s{2}` which means “exactly two whitespace characters.” For a simple example, consider a program that creates strings of zero to ten spaces and attempts to match them against a similar pattern.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

for (0 .. 10) {
  $_ = " " x $_;
  printf "%-13s %s\n", "[$_]:", /^(\s{2})+$/ ? "match!" : "no match.";
}
```

Output:

```
[]:           no match.
[ ]:          no match.
[  ]:         match!
[   ]:        no match.
[    ]:       match!
[     ]:      no match.
[      ]:     match!
[       ]:    no match.
[        ]:   match!
[         ]:  no match.
[          ]: match!
```

As written, your pattern substitutes a single TAB character for any *positive even number* of whitespace characters at logical beginning-of-line.

You don’t provide the broader context of your code. From the use of the `/m` and `/g` switches, I assume you have some hunk of text, perhaps the entire contents of a file, that you want to operate on as a whole. The program below simulates this assumed situation using a here-document and replaces the first two spaces only of each line with a TAB.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = <<EOText;
   Three
  Two
    Four
     Five
Zero
 One
EOText

s/^  /\t/mg;

# for display purposes only
s/\t/\\t/g;

print;
```

Output:

```
\t Three
\tTwo
\t  Four
\t   Five
Zero
 One
```

Note that the extra commented `s///` would not remain in your code. It is there to add contrast between space and TAB characters.

If this is the sole purpose of your program, it becomes an easy one-liner. To create a new file with the modified contents, use

```
$ perl -pe 's/^  /\t/' input-file >output-file
```

Editing in place looks like

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe 's/^  /\t/' input-file
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, without `/m` modifier you can use positive lookbehind. Such approach can be usefull for cases where you need to check something else, not just beginning of line, so when `\m` modifier would not help >>

```
$_ = "  123\n  456\n  789";
s/(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\n))\s{2}/\t/g;
print $_;
```

In the above example code each `/g` double whitespace `\s{2}` that is behind beginning of string `(?<=^)` or `(?: .. | .. )` new line character `(?<=\n)` is replaced by tab `\t`.