# convert all my xml document from whitespace to tab - notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am using tinyxml2 and unfortunately indents are treated as 4 whitespaces. I want to change this to tab but i don't know how. Is there any other way possible ? Can notepad++ automatically convert all my 80000 xml documents from whitespace to tabs ? The file is shown below, `<folder>` should be tabbed instead of 4 spaces.

```
<annotation>
    <folder>train</folder>
    <filename>004185</filename>
    <source>
        <database>KITTI database</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1242</width>
        <height>375</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segment>0</segment>
    <object>
        <name>Car</name>
        <pose>unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>339.49000000000001</xmin>
            <ymin>165.49000000000001</ymin>
            <xmax>476.13999999999999</xmax>
            <ymax>229.97999999999999</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Car</name>
        <pose>unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>376.77999999999997</xmin>
            <ymin>170.11000000000001</ymin>
            <xmax>498.54000000000002</xmax>
            <ymax>218.25</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Car</name>
        <pose>unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>784.83000000000004</xmin>
            <ymin>150.27000000000001</ymin>
            <xmax>840.88999999999999</xmax>
            <ymax>189.50999999999999</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Car</name>
        <pose>unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>412.88999999999999</xmin>
            <ymin>172.94</ymin>
            <xmax>514.10000000000002</xmax>
            <ymax>208.41</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Car</name>
        <pose>unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>434.24000000000001</xmin>
            <ymin>164.97999999999999</ymin>
            <xmax>530.09000000000003</xmax>
            <ymax>200.84</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Comment: Please show us a sample from your XML file(s).  Yes, Notepad++ might be able to do this, but we would need to see the file.

Comment: Hi thanks ! I have edited my post to include the xml file. Basically im trying to have all groups of "4 whitespaces" replaced with tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in a single file:

```
Edit -> Blank Operations -> Space to TAB (Leading)
```

This is dependent on your tab settings.

To do this in multiple files:

```
Find (Ctrl-F) -> Find in Files (tab)

Find what:  <4 spaces>
Replace with: /t
Directory: the directory that contains the files 
Filters: if needed a means of filtering eg file extension *.xml
Search mode: Extended
Then Replace In Files
```

If you need to only replace the spaces at the start of the line then there may be a regex solution.  This may help:

[perl replace space with tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311684/perl-replace-space-with-tab)

Comment: yea but i need to do it for 80,000 xml documents

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate replacing *all* occurrences of four spaces with tabs, then the following should work:

**Find:**

```
(type in four spaces)
```

**Replace:**

```
\t
```

Do this above find/replace in regex mode (select the regex option in the popup dialog).